# libnginx-mod-http-lua at ubuntu 21.10

Tags: nginx

According this: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libnginx-mod-http-lua

this module: `libnginx-mod-http-lua` just no longer available in newer version of ubuntu (newer than hirsute).

But I didn't see any news of it. My software stack just broken after I upgrade my ubuntu.

Will it add back again in ubuntu 22.04? or it just no longer supported by ubuntu team.
If that, is there any record of the decision of remove the package `libnginx-mod-http-lua`?

Comment: Next time you may want to build your enterprise hardware stack on relevant LTS (!) Ubuntu version. Debian has this package in place https://packages.debian.org/unstable/libnginx-mod-http-lua . So you have to report bug to Ubuntu Launchpad about this packaging issue. Here is the link https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bugs .

Comment: Do you know how to add distro tag like [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1893753)?  
I want add impish and hirsute in [my bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1951054)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround in jammy (22.04) is to install ondrej's PPA, which provides `libnginx-mod-http-lua`:

- [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/nginx](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/nginx)